# Query not showing expected results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column (`VARBINARY(128)`) in a table that I am trying to narrow results with the following query:

```
SELECT [ID], [DESCRP]
FROM PWNT.dbo.CHANNEL
WHERE 0x3100320033003A003A003000350030003100 NOT IN (SELECT FLDVALUE 
                                                     FROM PWNT.dbo.PARTI_M)
```

I know for a fact that the binary value `0x3100320033003A003A003000350030003100` exists in the `FLDVALUE` column, but I am not seeing the expected results when I run the query.

Am I doing something wrong?

(I have also tried changing `0x3100320033003A003A003000350030003100` to `SELECT 0x3100320033003A003A003000350030003100` in my query with the same result)

Thank you!

Comment: The expected result is an empty result. As the value exists, the `where` clause will be false for all records. Are you getting something other than an empty result?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the `FLDVALUE` takes on a NULL value.  Try doing this:

```
WHERE 0x3100320033003A003A003000350030003100 NOT IN (SELECT FLDVALUE FROM PWNT.dbo.PARTI_M WHERE FLDVALUE IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @AndriyM .. . That was a strange disconnect between my brain and my fingers.  I meant `NULL`.